# Cover all the edges of an undirected graph with fewest number of simple paths

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

Given an undirectd graph G, I want to cover all the edges with fewest simple paths.

For example, for a graph like this,

```
   B     E
   |     |
A--C--D--F--G
```

`A--C--D--F--G, B--C--D--F--E` is an optimum solution, whereas `A--C--D--F--G , B--C , E--F` is not.

Any algorithms?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? This smells like homework.

Comment: No, it is not homework stuff, I don't know if there is any constructive solution or if I have to do 'brute force' search.

Comment: All right, Just found a useful article called "Simple path covers in graphs"

Comment: Deciding whether one path is sufficient is NP-complete (the Hamiltonian path problem) so this problem is NP-hard.

Comment: However, there should be a simple(r) algorithm if we restrict ourselves to trees (like in the example in the question) or some other particular kind of graph

Comment: Do you need an exact cover (all edges exactly once rather than at least once)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as said by @RafalDowgird in comments, finding if one path is enough is the [Hamiltonian Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem), which is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), and there is no known polynomial algorithm for these problems.

This leaves you with 2 options:

1. Use heuristical solution, which might not be optimized. [example algorithm attached]
2. use exponential solution, such as [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)

for option one, you could try a greedy solution:

```
while (graph is not covered):
   pick arbitrary 2 connected not covered vertices v1,v2
   if there are none matching: 
       choose an arbitrary not covered vertex
       add an arbitrary path starting from this vertex
   else:   
       choose the longest simple path from v1 to v2 [can be found with BFS/DFS]
       add this path
```

for option two a naive backtracking solution will be

```
1. find P={all possible paths}
2. create S=2^P //the power set of P
3. chose s in S such that for each s' in S: |s| <= |s'| and both s,s' cover all vertices.
```

note that this solution is `O(2^(n!))`, so though it is optimal, it is not practical.

Comment: Thanks @amit. As you said this problem itself is NP-hard so I have to find some heuristical algorithms instead~