# Efficient robust algorithm for making paths in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I want to write a visualization for bonds in large molecules. The bonds are given as a list of connections, e.g.:

```
[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[5,6],[8,9]]
```

Up to now I am plotting every bond seperately with a single call to my visualization toolkit. This is however very slow and it is much faster to draw fewer but longer connected lines.

Therefore I would like to find as few as possible connected paths in my graph that draw all the connections. In my example I would like to convert the connection input e.g:

```
[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[5,6],[8,9],[6,8],[4,10]]
```

to

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,8,9],[4,10]]
```

Is there an efficient algorithm for that and are there implementations? I am writing in python but an algorithmic recipe would suffice (if it is not too complicated).

Comment: Just have a trouble to understand how the regroupment are being done. [1,2], [2,3], [3,4] are grouped since they intersect. But the others ? 7 is missing in the next one so why do you regroup 5,6,8 and 9 ? Why isn't the solution [[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[8,9],[4,10]]. Once i get that, won't be a problem to find an algorithm.

Comment: In your example, each origin only has one possible destination. In your more general case could [[1,2] [2,3][2,4]] occur? If so how would that effect what the desired results would be? It seems you just need to reduce the number of lines rather than find the minimum possible number of lines.

Comment: Is this 2D or 3D? It seems odd that you can replace [[1, 2], [2, 3]] with [[1, 2, 3]] unless the bonds are colinear. In any case, it kind of sounds like you want the connected components? What happens if that component is a tree? eg : [[1,2],[2,3],[2,4]]?

Comment: Why the solution is [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,8,9],[4,10]] and not [[1,2,3,4,10],[5,6,8,9]]?

Comment: algrid: Your are totally right the solution is  [[1,2,3,4,10],[5,6,8,9]]. @gilleain It should be independent of the dimension. The numbers are labels of the points. rox: The case can occur and then the algorithm should just minimize the number of paths. The result could then be [[1,2] [2,3][2,4]] -> [[1,2,3],[2,4]]

Comment: @Jannick take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148231/cover-all-the-edges-of-an-undirected-graph-with-fewest-number-of-simple-paths?rq=1 The only difference may be in disabling edge repetitions in your resulting paths (if you want that). Anyway it looks like NP-hard problem so in practice you should end up with an heuristic.